# Middle part of a fence using terrain representation

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, math

I'm making a fence using terrain representation where 1's is fenced land and 0's are empty spaces. Here would be a map for example:

0110

1111

1111

1101

How the code works is it scans the corners and the sides of 1's and counts how many meters of fence you would need, where every side of a 1 is 2.5m. The j variable is like the x value and the i is the y value.I have the working code for the sides and the corners, the only thing I need help with is how i would go about setting a for loop for the center of the fences. Here is my working code:

```
package workspace;

public class Fencing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean b = true;
    double corner = 0;
    double center = 0;
    double side = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int[][] map = { 
        { 0, 1, 1, 0 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
        { 1, 1, 0, 1 } 
    };
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] != 1 && map[i][j] != 0) {
                b = false;
                System.out.println("--> A value of " + map[i][j] + " was found at " + i + "," + j);
            }
        }
    }
    if (b == false && i == 3) {
        System.out.println("The map is invalid");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Map is valid");
    }
    if (map[0][0] == 1) {
        corner += 5;
        if (map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] == 1) {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
            corner += 5;
        }
        if (map[1][0] != 1 && map[0][1] == 1 || map[1][0] == 1 && map[0][1] != 1) {
            corner += 2.5;
        }
    } else {
        corner += 0;
    }
    if (map[0][3] == 1) {
        corner += 5;
        if (map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] == 1) {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
            corner += 5;
        }
        if (map[1][3] != 1 && map[0][2] == 1 || map[1][3] == 1 && map[0][2] != 1) {
            corner += 2.5;
        }
    } else {
        corner += 0;
    }
    if (map[3][0] == 1) {
        corner += 5;
        if (map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] == 1) {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[02][0] != 1) {
            corner += 5;
        }
        if (map[3][1] != 1 && map[2][0] == 1 || map[3][1] == 1 && map[2][0] != 1) {
            corner += 2.5;
        }
    } else {
        corner += 0;
    }
    if (map[3][3] == 1) {
        corner += 5;
        if (map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] == 1) {
            corner += 0;
        }
        if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
            corner += 5;
        }
        if (map[3][2] != 1 && map[2][3] == 1 || map[3][2] == 1 && map[2][3] != 1) {
            corner += 2.5;
        }
    } else {
        corner += 0;
    }
    System.out.println("Corner fencing = " + corner);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) { // Top
        if (map[0][j] == 1) {
            side += 2.5;
            if (map[0][j + 1] == 1 && map[0][j - 1] == 1) {
                side += 0;
            }
            if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 || map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                side += 2.5;
            }
            if (map[0][j + 1] != 1 && map[0][j - 1] != 1) {
                side += 5;
            }
        } else {
            side += 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After the first row, fencing = " + side);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (j = 1; j < 3; j++) { // Bottom
        if (map[3][j] == 1) {
            side += 2.5;
            if (map[3][j + 1] == 1 && map[3][j - 1] == 1) {
                side += 0;
            }
            if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 || map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                side += 2.5;
            }
            if (map[3][j + 1] != 1 && map[3][j - 1] != 1) {
                side += 5;
            }
        } else {
            side += 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After the bottom row, fencing = " + side);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {// Right
        if (map[i][3] == 1) {
            side += 2.5;
            if (map[i + 1][3] == 1 && map[i - 1][3] == 1) {
                side += 0;
            }
            if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 || map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                side += 2.5;
            }
            if (map[i + 1][3] != 1 && map[i - 1][3] != 1) {
                side += 5;
            }
        } else {
            side += 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After the first column, fencing = " + side);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {// Left
        if (map[i][0] == 1) {
            side += 2.5;
            if (map[i + 1][0] == 1 && map[i - 1][0] == 1) {
                side += 0;
            }
            if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 || map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                side += 2.5;
            }
            if (map[i + 1][0] != 1 && map[i - 1][0] != 1) {
                side += 5;
            }
        } else {
            side += 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After the last column, fencing = " + side);

}
}
```

I'm unsure if i would even use a for loop to scan the core, but I imagine it would be something like the side loops. Anyone have an idea on what the code would look like?

Comment: what is the desired output for the example?

Comment: For the certain map i provided (which is the same one as the one in the array) it would be 2.5, since there is only one 1 in the center that is next to a 0

Comment: If you ask this question at codereview.stackexchange.com, they will propose a much cleaner way of writing it, so that it is both shorter and easier to understand. You have a lot of copy-pasting going around, and whenever you copy-paste code, there's a better way of doing things.

Comment: *"since there is only one 1 in the center that is next to a 0"* so the logic is: find all `0`s and then find all horizontal/vertical neigbours which are `1`s and not border fields. right?

Comment: Opposite of that, the code looks for 1's horizontally and vertically, then if it sees that it is not next to another 1 it adds 2.5 to one of the three variables depending on where it is

Answer (score 0):

So given a matrix of zeroes and ones, you want to count how many transitions from one-to-zero (up-down, left-right) you can find. Each of those will result in a 2.5m stretch of fence. Borders count as zero.

You have a lot of copy-pasted if-statements to check for this. I propose the following rewrite, which uses methods to avoid copy-pasting code.

```
/**
 * returns the number of zero-or-border neighbors for a 1 
 * in a 2D array of ints that can be either 1 or 0
 */
public static int bordersFor(int[][] map, int row, int col) {
    int borders = 0;
    // left
    if (col == 0 || map[row][col-1] == 0) borders ++;
    // right
    if (col == map[0].length-1 || map[row][col+1] == 0) borders ++;
    // up
    if (row == 0 || map[row-1][col] == 0) borders ++;
    // down
    if (row == map.length-1 || map[row+1][col] == 0) borders ++;

    return borders;
}

public static int bordersFor(int[][] map) {
    int borders = 0;
    for (int row=0; row<map.length; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<map[0].length; col++) {
            if (map[row][col] == 1) borders += bordersFor(map, row, col);
        }
    }
    return borders;
}

public static void main(String ... args) {
    int[][] map = {
            { 0, 1, 1, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
            { 1, 1, 0, 1 }
    };
    System.out.println(bordersFor(map));
}
```